# Problems on Both Parsing Legal JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, jsonlint

I have a problem on both parsing legal and validated JSON objects.

This one runs okay

```
var response = {"tags":"[{\"value\": 2,\"label\": \"Dubstep\"},{\"value\": 3,\"label\": \"BoysIIMen\"},{\"value\": 4,\"label\":\"Sylenth1\"}]"};

var tags = $.parseJSON(response.tags);
console.log(tags);
```

It Prints Out on the Console `Array[3]`

but when I run I change the value of `var response` to this one

```
 var response = {"tag":"[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Dubstep\",\"description\":\"Dub wob wob\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"BoysIIMen\",\"description\":\"A 1990s Boy Band\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Sylenth1\",\"description\":\"A VST Plugin for FLStudio \"}]"};
```

the value of `tags` is `null` take note that both values are validated on JSONLint.

Comment: Because in the second case, the property name is `tag`, not `tags`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second scenario, since you have changed "tags" to "tag", are you parsing the JSON as below - note the missing 's' in reponse.tag?

```
var tags = $.parseJSON(response.tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example starts:

```
{"tag":
```

This should be

```
{"tags":
```